# Filter select options in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ng-options

In my Angularjs application, i am having code as follows,

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="showvalidrates"> Display only Valid Rates
    <br><br>
        <select ng-model="selectRate" 
        ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in data">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('test', [])
    .controller('test', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.data = [
      {name: 'Rate 1', id: 1, valid: true}, 
      {name: 'Rate 2', id: 2, valid: false},
      {name: 'Rate 3', id: 3, valid: true}
      ];
      $scope.selectRate = $scope.data[1].id;
      $scope.showvalidrates = true;
}]);
```

Here i am making `ng-options` to display the rates, and i am having a checkbox which will be in checked state by default.

In this scenario, i am in the need to filter the `ng-options` to display only the valid rates for which i am having a property called `valid: true` or `valid: false`.

Here if the checkbox is checked which means `showvalidrates` is true, then only the object with `valid: true` needs to be displayed in options.. But if the value is selected already, In the working example given below `{name: 'Rate 2', id: 2, valid: false}` is selected but it has `valid: false` in this case the selected value needs to be displayed (means `Rate 2` only needs to be in selected state).  unless user touches the select box, but if he clicks the select box then only valid rates needs to be displayed and he can select any of the valid rates.

And if he uncheck the `showvalidrates` (false) then all the rates needs to be displayed in `ng-options` ..

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/opygzs4a/

As per example given,

```
showvalidrates = true

Options: 

Rate 1

Rate 2 (Selected)

Rate 3
```

Onclick on the select box only Rate 1 and Rate 3 needs to displayed and user can select any of these two.

Unless any of these two were chosen the `Rate 2` alone needs to be in selected state and `selectRate` should have the value as 2 only.

The `valid` property was the newly implemented in code to filter the data, so in order to affect the earlier `selectRate` value in the application, this scenario needs to be implemented.(Even if valid is false let it be selected unless user changes)..

I am very new in AngularJs and this scenario, so please help me how to handle this situation..

If there is any alternative approach for it it would be also welcomed but requirement is the same as like mentioned above.

Comment: Are you trying to display options with flag- valid true and looking for something like this - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/jjywBK?editors=1010? For this option, use filter - ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in data|filter:{valid:true}

Comment: @NagaSaiA, I have explained the expected result in your solution as comment..

Answer (score 2):

To achieve expected result , use below option of using filter with checkbox condition

ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in data|filter: !init && showvalidrates?{valid:true}:{}" ng-init="init = true">

1. On check, showvalidrates is true and based on that set filter as { valid: true } to display options with flag valid -true
2. On uncheck, showvalidrates is false and based on that set filter as {}
3. Add ng-init flag to control initial default value

Codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GbrOMm?editors=1010

working code sample

```js
angular.module('test', [])
    .controller('test', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.data = [
      {name: 'Rate 1', id: 1, valid: true}, 
      {name: 'Rate 2', id: 2, valid: false},
      {name: 'Rate 3', id: 3, valid: true}
      ];
      $scope.selectRate = $scope.data[1].id;
      $scope.showvalidrates = true;
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="showvalidrates" ng-change="init = false"> Display only Valid Rates
    <br><br>
        <select ng-model="selectRate" 
        ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in data|filter: !init && showvalidrates?{valid:true}:{}" ng-init="init = true" ng-click="init = false">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP also wants the option that is "not valid" to show if it has been selected, but since you are filtering it out of the list of options it won't show.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But i am in the need to display the selected value default despite of the checkbox selection.. Meaning ```$scope.selectRate = $scope.data[1].id;``` says ```Rate 2``` is selected so this value needs to be displayed default.. On click of the select box again, only two (valid) rates needs to be displayed but until then ```Rate 2``` only needs to be selected and ```selectRate``` should hold the value as ```2``` until changed.. as like my working example.. Hope you understand the requirement..

Comment: @ManirajfromKarur, updated my answer with ng-init to control initial value, Hope it works :)

Comment: @NagaSaiA, But on click the select box user needs to see only two rates but your updated demo shows three rates.. I am not sure to handle this thing and i think the whole things needs to be customized to achieve the result.. Because user cannot be allowed to select again ```Rate 2``` after clicking ```Rate 1``` or ```Rate 3``` (User able to select Rate 2  in your solution).. It would be helpful if you take time and give better solution.. For more info, eventhough you display all three with the checkbox true, user needs to be prevented from selecting ```Rate 2``` if he selects another rates..

Comment: updated answer with ng-click="init = false"  to select would fix that part -https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GbrOMm

Comment: @NagaSaiA, I have made a change in the example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NZdXWE , here i have changed ```Rate 1``` as selected but still why three rates were displayed as checkbox is checked to display only valid rates??

Comment: @NagaSaiA, In this example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wLgpaY i have given ```Rate 1```, ```Rate 2``` and ```Rate 3``` as selected respectively for three dropdown.. And i am making the checkbox as unchecked  and if check it again the value in the second selectbox disappears.. (Please check and uncheck the checkbox to see this change in the codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wLgpaY)

Comment: @NagaSaiA, I still appreciate your solution but its not able to get full structured as per my requirement.. But as of now you have given very good approach, it would be much more helpful if you sort out my above two scenarios.. I am sure that i will accept your answer if the issues were sorted out..

Comment: on checking checkbox, invalid options are filtered out and default selection option Rate 2 is not available and it displays blank option

Comment: @NagaSaiA, But unless i select another option, i need to have ```Rate 2``` as the value know?? If we are removing it then there will not be any value and its not expected, until other option was selected, the default option value needs to be binded to model..

Comment: @NagaSaiA, Also on load, if checkbox is checked, i am able to see all three options which is not expected.. I also request you to consider the case if the select box has repeated mutiple times inside for loop and each has different state..

Comment: @NagaSaiA, For now to your efforts i have given an upvote, if you give me full structured scenario, i will accept this solution.. Thanks..